# Creating a lot of DOM elements. which method is faster? Echoing the HTML or using PHP DOM class?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I need to create about 10k elements when a user visit my site, its sort of a big tree like `<ul>` and `<li>`.

The process of creating the HTML currently takes about 15 seconds, i create the HTML in an array then json_encode and echo it.

i am trying to shorten the process. my question is:

would it be faster to use php's [DOM](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) class to create the elements.

or just create the HTML and echo it?

Comment: Its just the HTML for something like JStree and is nested, but thanks for the input

Comment: Is there anyway you could create the list once every hour (for example), and then cache the html to a file?

Comment: Are you sure that it's the process of creating that takes 15 seconds or is it the actual network transfer from server to you that takes 15 seconds?

Comment: well the list is only created ones and is saved but the 15-20 second load is still crazy and i am trying to reduce that

Comment: N.B Well, i am not entirely sure to really, i am pretty sure its the creation as it kind stuck in JS stage where the element is being appended

Comment: So the issue is evaluating a quite big JSON into a proper javascript object and traversing it. I see nothing related to PHP or PHP's DOM object..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

15 seconds to create and json_encode 10K elements .. this can't be right. The bottle neck is undoubtedly not PHP here. Where is that data coming from, a database ? In a single query or embedded queries in a loop ? Can the data be cached ? If so, do so.

You need to properly benchmark before optimizing, what you're trying to do now is trim milliseconds off an operation that takes 15 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

> *(rather too much here to fit in a comment - I don't think the question can or should be answered in it's current form)*

Would it be so hard to find out for yourself?

Why do you create your data as a json data structure?

Surely you don't then convert it back to HTML on PHP?

Why not just write PHP?

Have you profiled your code to verify if the slow bit is generating the output rather than fetching the input?

Who is going to read 10k bullet points?

You've not shown us any code - and I don't know why or how you are using JSON. But using intermediate data structures (DOM or JSON) will be significantly slower than writing directly to the output buffer.

Comment: would it be hard to try my self - basically will have to redo everything I've done so far though of asking before doing another mistake, it seemed to be the right idea when i made it, which turn to be wrong, by what people say here i assume I'll have to PHP it only. As for showing code it was a general question to know which approach to take is all.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is simple DOM hierarchy; just echo it!