# PHP DOM Creation vs echo HTML

Tags: php, dom, echo

*I apologize in advance if this is deemed not constructive...*

**Which is better to do?**

1. **echo** out html code

   ```
   echo("<div>marry me natalie imbruglia... please</div>");
   ```

   **OR**
2. > ```
   >    $dom = new DOMDocument("1.0","utf-8");
   >
   >    element = $dom->createElement('test', 'This is the root element!');
   >
   >    $dom->appendChild($element);
   >
   >    echo $dom->saveXML();
   > ```

*I must also mention that the platform i'm using at work does not support this... please do not ask why, it is the way it is... i have to work within those bounds...*

Comment: This may answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087086/creating-a-lot-of-dom-elements-which-method-is-faster-echoing-the-html-or-usin

Comment: which code would you rather support?

Comment: You could also use just output the html and use PHP when you need it. You can mix PHP and HTML using `<? ?>` to open and close PHP

Comment: that was an option tacos, but the cms i'm using does not support escaping html into php... sadnesss... but thanks

Comment: thanks +George, tried searching for posts similar to my question, its a bit tricky! this should help! :) thank you

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by better? Do you mean better performance?

Comment: not necessarily performance, In terms of semantics... there must be a reason that theres a DOMDocument creation function in php, i just cant see the advantage of using it... it is alot more code after all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would choose neither.  Since I am used to Java Server Pages, I would rather use straight HTML/PHP interleaving like so ...

```
<?php $x
$x = "This is the root element!";
?>
<test><?= $x ?></test>
```

**If I had to choose from one of the two options you provided, I would definitely go with the second one because it's much easier to modify the final XML structure in the future.**

I'll just emphasize Darryl's comment in an earlier post - since I don't have the enough reputation right now to add a further comment underneath his.  Maintenance which is often correlated to code readability is important.  If you are asking this question because you are trying to squeeze out "performance" then you're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that im not able to do that on the platform im bound to

Comment: No problem, Craig.  I bolded my answer above which is in-bounds.

Comment: ah this is true! i suppose it's semantically correct... easier to understand, although more coding...

thanks again! geniet jou dag